# ios swift show/hide an element in textView cell and clear its space

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a dynamic tableView. TableViewCell prototype looks like this:

"------------------"
 label
 segmentedControl  (yes | no)
 textView
"------------------"

My question is how can i hide and then show textView that tableView can autoresize its cell height

Here is my tableViewCell class:

```
class QuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var question: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var answer: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var comment: UITextView!
```

And here is my tableView cellForRowAtIndex:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("QuestionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionTableViewCell

    cell.question.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). " + questions[indexPath.row]
    // check answer and set it to segmentedControl and set color
    if questionsAnswers[indexPath.row] == "YES" {
        cell.answer.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        cell.answer.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x42DC5A)
    } else {
        cell.answer.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        cell.answer.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0xD9393E)
    }

    if cell.comment != nil {
        cell.comment.delegate = self
        cell.comment.text = "Add a note if necessary.."
        cell.comment.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }

    if questionsAnswers[indexPath.row] == "YES" {
        // here i have to hide cell.comment and its space
    } else {
        // here i have to show it if its possible
    }

    // pass indexPath.row to action
    cell.answer.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.answer.addTarget(self, action: "valueChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    return cell
}

// fires when user taps on segmentedControl
func valueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl){
    // switch segment and update questionsAnswers array
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        questionsAnswers[sender.tag] = "YES"
        sender.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x42DC5A)
    case 1:
        questionsAnswers[sender.tag] = "NO"
        sender.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0xD9393E)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

questions - an array with text of question
questionsAnswers - an array when i save value from segmented control

Sorry if my question is bad, i'm newbie in ios programming(

Comment: Create height constraint to the textView and set it to zero or some value depending on preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the xib in the interface builder. Then ctrl + drag the constraints to the UIViewController for that view.

For your case you will need a height of `textView` and spacing between either `segmentedControl` or the bottom layout.

After that just set your `heightConstraint.constant = 0` and `spacingConstraint.constant = 0`.

If you only set the height one, you will have two spacings between the `segmentedControl` and the bottom layout as it is suggested in other answers.

If you need to show it again, just make sure you save the initial values for constraint constants and then set them back like this `heightConstraint.constant = initialHeight` and `spacingConstraint.constant = initialSpacing`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Auto Layout, you could add a height constraint to the text view, and add an `IBOutlet` to it in your cell subclass. Just set `myConstraint.constant` to zero if you want to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, i created an IBOutlet for textView's height constraint in my tableViewCell class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then i replace this code:

```
if questionsAnswers[indexPath.row] == "YES" {
    cell.heightConstraint.constant = 0.0
} else {
    cell.heightConstraint.constant = 70.0
}
```

And it works well, but i got this in the debugger:

> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

```
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9fc2f45300 V:[UITextView:0x7f9fc3017a00'Add a note if necessary..'(70)]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9fc2df4460 UILabel:0x7f9fc2f40410'3. Question sadsadas das ...'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9fc2f402d0.topMargin>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9fc2df4550 V:[UILabel:0x7f9fc2f40410'3. Question sadsadas das ...']-(NSSpace(8))-[UISegmentedControl:0x7f9fc2f40e20]>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9fc2df4700 UITextView:0x7f9fc3017a00'Add a note if necessary..'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9fc2f402d0.bottomMargin>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9fc2df4750 V:[UISegmentedControl:0x7f9fc2f40e20]-(NSSpace(8))-[UITextView:0x7f9fc3017a00'Add a note if necessary..']>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9fc2ed5060 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9fc2f402d0(81.5)]>" )
```

Should i change some constraints? 
And one more question if user click "NO" on segmentedControl i want to show that textView to user.
Can i do it like this:

```
// pass indexPath.row to action
cell.answer.tag = indexPath.row
cell.answer.addTarget(self, action: "valueChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

// fires when user taps on segmentedControl
func valueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl){
    // switch segment and update questionsAnswers array
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        questionsAnswers[sender.tag] = "YES"
        sender.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x42DC5A)
        tableView.reloadData()
    case 1:
        questionsAnswers[sender.tag] = "NO"
        sender.tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0xD9393E)
        tableView.reloadData()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Just reload tableView with new questionsAnswers array?

Comment: For the second part, yes. You just need to update your model and then reload table view.